# Android Development Tool (ADT) Plugin is not showing in Eclipse

Tags: installation, eclipse-adt

The Android Development Tool (ADT) Plugin is not showing in Eclipse 4.4.0 on Ubuntu Linux, despite being installed.

I have tried:
sudo /opt/eclipse/eclipse -clean
and several complete re-installs of Eclipse.
On my several retries, the ADT sometimes did show up in the preferences, and asked for the SDK Location. Which I don't know, since I used Eclipse's Install new software interface. I've never been pointed to any install location. I can't find any file named android-sdk*.

1) How can I make the ADT show up?
2) When the ADT shows up in preferences, which directory is the SDK Location?

I've searched far and wide on Stackoverflow and elsewhere, but question 1) was always answered with 'un-install and re-install the ADT', which doesn't work, and question 2) was always considered a given; no actual directory was indicated in anything I found.
So much kudos to who can tell me!

Answer (score 0):

One common problem is being in an Eclipse perspective other than Java. For example, if you are in perspective Java EE, Android ADT menu won't show.

Not sure about the SDK location when installed from ADT but it is probably an android directory in your home directory (/root/android or /home/user/android)